# Get just the page name with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use `.htaccess` to get just the page name. For example, given the following:

```
domain.com/pagename.php
domain.com/dir/pagename.html
domain.com/dir/dir/pagename.htm
domain.com/pagename.php?param=abc
domain.com/dir/pagename.asp?param=abc
domain.com/dir/dir/pagename.php?param=abc
```

what I want to isolate `pagename`, but still retain the original URL. I want to pass this to PHP using a parameter `filename=$1`.Thus the output (respectively) for all of the above would be:

```
domain.com/pagename.php?filename=pagename
domain.com/dir/pagename.html?filename=pagename
domain.com/dir/dir/pagename.htm?filename=pagename
domain.com/pagename.php?param=abc?filename=pagename
domain.com/dir/pagename.asp?param=abc?filename=pagename
domain.com/dir/dir/pagename.php?param=abc?filename=pagename
```

I'm trying this with the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.+)\.(.+) $1/$2.$3?filename=$2 [QSA]
```

I think that should grab zero or more directories in $1, the filename in $2, and the extension in $3.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*\/)?([^\/]*\/)?([a-z]+)\.([a-z]{3,4}) $1$2$3.$4?filename=$3 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^((?:.+/)*(.+?)\.[a-z0-9]{3,4})$ $1?filename=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Without `RewriteCond`, because they are real files